# Protractor stacktrace does not mention the line number on the .js file where the syntax issue or error occurs

Tags: protractor

This is my conf.js

```
exports.config = {
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
specs: ['C:\\Users\\meiyer\\Desktop\\Protractor_Tests\\specs\\specs.js'],
baseUrl: 'https://devcp.us.sunpowermonitor.com/#/dashboard',
// Framework to use. Jasmine is recommended.
framework: 'jasmine',
//Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
jasmineNodeOpts: {
  onComplete: null,
  isVerbose: true,
  showColors: true,
  includeStackTrace: true
 }
 };
```

This is my specs.js

```
var elhLoginpage = {
nameInput : element(by.model('user.UserName')),
passInput : element(by.model('model')),
submitButton :element(by.buttonText('sign in')),
setEmail: function(email) {
this.nameInput.sendKeys(email);
},
setPass: function(password) {
this.passInput.sendKeys(password);
},
clickSubmit:function(){
this.submitButton.click();
}
};

var elhHomepage = {
greetingText : element(by.css('.greeting-des')),
getgreetingText: function() {
this.greetingText.text();
}
};


describe('elhLoginpage login test', function() {
it('should land on homepage when valid username and password is entered',
  function(){
elhLoginpage.setEmail('lease_id@test.com');
elhLoginpage.setPass('sun');
elhLoginpage.clickSubmit();
expect(elhHomepage.getgreetingText().toEqual('Hello lease');
});
});
```

I am executing the test on node.js command prompt as ->  protractor conf.js. I am getting below stack trace. From the information below -I am not able to debug on which line number on either of the .js files the issue has occurred. Is there a way to activate this information on stacktrace?

Stacktrace -

```
  C:\Users\meiyer\Desktop\Protractor_Tests>protractor conf.js
  [15:40:56] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at 
  http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
  [15:40:56] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
  [15:40:58] E/launcher - Error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at  
   C:\Users\meiyer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\
   jasmine\lib\jasmine.js:71:5
   at Array.forEach (native)
   at Jasmine.loadSpecs   
   C:\Users\meiyer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protr
    actor\node_modules\jasmine\lib\jasmine.js:70:18)
   [15:40:58] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unforunately that can be a common error in protractor for syntax issues.  It's hard to tell without code indentation, but the error is about a missing `)` and at a quick glance it looks like you are missing one in your final `expect` statement.

You have:

```
expect(elhHomepage.getgreetingText().toEqual('Hello lease');
```

It should be:

```
expect(elhHomepage.getgreetingText()).toEqual('Hello lease');
```

You can use linters like [ES Lint](http://eslint.org/) to quickly find syntax errors like this.

Comment: I would actually recommend a more feature-rich and modern linter - `ESLint`.